# C programming homework question involving arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have a program that asks the user to select to `add class/ drop class / print invoice`. Classes are saved as arrays. I am having a problem with the invoice. I have two functions to list the `course name` and `course credits` to then be passed in the `print invoice function`.

However, when the user inputs more than one class, the first class has the appropriate class string name and credits in the invoice. The following classes are the accurate course number `array` but copy the same credits and class name. I tried different solutions, making the functions return a pointer, but had no luck. Any advice would be helpful thanks!

Tried having function print/ return pointer

```
void printInvoice(int crn[], int idNumber){
    int i;
            printf("\n\t\tFee Invoice Prepared for Student:\n\t\t%d", idNumber);

            for ( i=1; i<MAX_CLASS ; i++){
                if ( crn[i] != 0 ){
                    printf ("\n\t\t%d\t%s\t\t%d", crn[i], printPrefix(crn), getCredits(crn) );
                }
            }

}

int getCredits(int crn[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < MAX_CLASS; i++){
        switch(crn[i]){
            case 4587: return 4;
                break;
            case 4599: return 3;
                break;
            case 8997: return 1;
                break;
            case 9696: return 3;
                break;
            case 7895: return 2;
                break;
            case 9658: return 3;
                break;
            case 4287: return 4;
                break;
            case 9599: return 3;
                break;
            case 8927: return 1;
                break;
            case 7696: return 4;
                break;
            case 7890: return 3;    
                break;
            case 9008: return 5;
                break;
        }
    }
}

char* printPrefix(int crn[]){

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < MAX_CLASS; i++){
        switch(crn[i]){
            case 4587: return "MAT 236";
            case 4599: return "COP 220";
            case 8997: return "GOL 124";
            case 9696: return "COP 100";
            case 7895: return "MNT 125";
            case 9658: return "OPT 120";
            case 4287: return "MAT 836";
            case 9599: return "COP 220";
            case 8927: return "GOM 124";
            case 7696: return "COT 100";
            case 7890: return "MOT 125";    
            case 9008: return "OPT 520";
        }
    }
}
```

Expect corresponding class name and credit number .
Actual results are first array (course) entered copies their class name and credit number for following arrays

Comment: You are missing the default in the switch statement

Comment: In *both* switch statements.

Comment: Wheres the main function? did you define MAXSIZE ? Make sure your counter doesn't need to start at 0 for your loops.

Answer (score 1):

In each of your functions:

```
for(i = 1; i < MAX_CLASS; i++){
    switch(crn[i]){
        case 4587: return 4;
            break;
            ...
```

You enter a loop, then you return a value based on `crn[0]`, so you only ever go through the first iteration of the loop.

You don't need loops in these functions at all.  Instead of passing in the entire `crn` array, pass in the array element you're interested and operate on just that.

So change your functions to:

```
int getCredits(int crn){
    switch(crn){
        case 4587: return 4;
        ...
        default: return -1;
    }
}

char* printPrefix(int crn){
    switch(crn){
        case 4587: return "MAT 236";
        ...
        default: return "";
    }
}
```

And call them as:

```
printf ("\n\t\t%d\t%s\t\t%d", crn[i], printPrefix(crn[i]), getCredits(crn[i]) );
```

Note also that `default` cases are added for each `switch` so something always gets returned.

Comment: thank you! sorry if that was a silly question my prof explained it pretty fast